# Which of the many Spark/Scala kernels for Jupyter/IPython to choose?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ipython, jupyter

There are a lot of Scala/Spark kernels for IPython/Jupyter:

1. [IScala](https://github.com/mattpap/IScala)
2. [ISpark](https://github.com/tribbloid/ISpark)
3. [Jupyter Scala](https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala)
4. [Apache Toree](https://toree.incubator.apache.org/)(prev [Spark Kernel](https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel))

Does anybody know wich of them is most compatible with IPython/Jupyter and most comfortable to use with:

1. Scala
2. Spark(Scala)

Comment: The IPython wiki has a list of many kernels (including other languages besides scala). Thought I would add it here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages

Comment: Useful to comment if these come as source, binary or both. And the ease of installation, both on Win10/Linux/MacOS. Also, how do they compare to each other on CPU and memory performance? security? patches? magic commands?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can't speak for all of them, but I use Spark Kernel and it works very well for using both Scala and Spark.

I found IScala and Jupyter Scala less stable and less polished.  Jupyter Scala always prints every variable value after I execute a cell; I don't want to see this 99% of the time.

Spark Kernel is my favourite.  Both for Spark and plain old Scala.

Comment: How is difficult to run it?

Comment: Can it drow plot to IPython?

Comment: I haven't tried drawing plots with it, but i see no reason why it would not work.

They were all very easy to run once they are installed.

Answer (score 5):

**Spark Kernel** has been accepted into **Apache Incubator** and has moved all development to [Apache Toree](https://toree.incubator.apache.org/documentation/user/quick-start).

Comment: Are you recommending it or just commenting? How does it compare on CPU and memory performance, install size, ease of install, etc?

Answer (score 4):

I have been using spark-kernel (your option #4) and quite satisfied.

You can find a nice how-to installation (CDH 5.5 on CentOS 7) here (I have used it myself to install it in a Single node in pseudo-distributed mode).

http://www.davidgreco.me/blog/2015/12/24/how-to-use-jupyter-with-spark-kernel-and-cloudera-hadoop-slash-spark/